Derivative on a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ through a curve
I am a beginner in differential geometry and have been trying to find the gradient of the great arc distance $f(x) = d(x,y) = \arccos(\langle x, y\rangle)$ with respect to $x$, but getting two different results that I cannot seem to unify.
I am using $S^{n-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ as a Riemannian manifold with the canonical metric pulled from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since we are on a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can take the usual gradient of the function and project it orthogonally onto the tangent space, obtaining: $$\mathrm{grad} \,\,d(x,y) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\langle x,y \rangle^2}}[I-xx^T]y$$
However, if I understand correctly, there should be an equivalent result through any smooth curve $c(t):[0,1]\to S^{n-1}$ with $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0) = v$ such that $$(f \circ c)'(0) = \mathrm{D}f(x)[v] = \langle \mathrm{grad}\,f,v\rangle_x$$ with $\mathrm{D}f(x)[v]$ denoting the directional derivative in the direction of $v$. From this approach, I keep getting $$(f \circ c)'(0) = \mathrm{D}f(x)[v] = \Big\langle \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-\langle x,y \rangle^2}},v\Big\rangle$$ i.e., the $\mathrm{grad}f(x) = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-\langle x,y \rangle^2}}$ which is not even in $T_x{S^{n-1}}$.
Does someone please have any hints as to what I am missing in the calculation?

Are you familiar with a covariant derivative? From how I see it, you don’t take into account the fact that the derivative along the curve should keep the gradient within the tangent bundle, that’s what covariant derivative is for.

Oh, like a connection? I haven't considered that, thanks. If you had any more hints I would be thankful as I am kind of out of my depth here

Correct, that vector is not even orthogonal to the sphere, so you need to project orthogonally before you can conclude what is the gradient on the sphere. Your computation goes through verbatim for all vectors $v$, not just those tangent to the sphere, so the thing you computed is the gradient in the ambient $\Bbb{R}^n$. So, you’ve just jumped the gun and made a simple linear algebra blunder.

@EgorLarionov covariant derivatives are not relevant here since OP only has to differentiate a real-valued function defined on the sphere. So connections and covariant derivatives are a red herring here. Also, as mentioned in my previous comment to OP, the mistake is simply they didn’t project things in the second approach.

If we parametrize the sphere with polar angle $\theta$ and azimuth $\varphi$ and consider a scalar function $f(\theta,\varphi)$ its gradient on the sphere is
$$
(\partial_\theta f),\hat{\theta}+\tfrac 1{\sin\theta}(\partial_\varphi f),\hat{\varphi}
$$
where $\hat{\theta},\hat{\varphi}$ are normalized basis vectors w.r.t the metric $ds^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta,d\varphi^2,.$
